# Can multiple inquiries with only one mortgage lender over months hurt your credit?

Tags: credit-score, home-loan, home

We applied for a home loan in the beginning of January and was told to wait 2 months. I want to know if multiple credit inquiries from only ONE lender will hurt or does it count as one creditor? Over a several month period.

Comment: Not really an answer but if you're afraid of them hitting your account multiple times you can always freeze your credit and only un-freeze it when they need to pull a report.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, one lender should only need to run one "hard" credit inquiry when you are applying for the loan. They may also require a second inquiry just before closing to confirm your situation has not changed. What is counted for credit purposes is the number of inqiries, not the number of lenders. However, this level of activity should not impact your credit significantly.

A more problematic scenario is if you are also getting quotes from multiple lenders in a short period of time, which can impact your scores more significantly.